# Positive rationals satisfying: $a^2+a^2=c^2$?

Tags: exponentiation, rational-numbers

If there are none why not?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Nigh-trivially, if there were then the square root of two would be rational ($a^2+a^2=c^2$, so $2a^2=c^2$, so $2=\frac{c^2}{a^2}$).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note that this can be written as $$2=\left(\frac{c}a\right)^2$$

Is $\sqrt 2$ rational?